# "Versioning" JAXB object?

Tags: jaxb

We're building a many developer app using JAXB and keep stumbling on problems that all come back to a "version" mismatch between producers and consumers of JAXB objects.

Process hasn't alleviated the pain so I was thinking about something along the lines of CORBA object versioning for JAXB, maybe via a required final field whose values must match. As an added bonus I'd like to inject the version value as the Maven version # :-)

This is all using annotations, no xsd.

Thoughts?

Thanks.

----- Clarification -----

Think of this as a Serializable serialVersionUID that is added to the marshal stream when the object is marshaled and is required and whose value is *checked* when the object is unmarshaled.

Various check rules can be implemented, but in this case I only want equality. If the current version of a Foo is 1.1 and you send me data to unmarshal whose version is anything other than 1.1 I will reject it.

Help?

Comment: Not getting the question. Can you be specific. There are many people who doesn't know CORBA.

Comment: Have you thought about using protocol buffers? They are build for this exact purpose and work very well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

**Foo**

Add a version field to your root model object.

```java
package forum12218164;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    @XmlAttribute
    public static final String VERSION = "123";

    private String bar;

    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

In your demo code leverage a StAX parser to check the version attribute before determining if it is safe to perform the unmarshal operation:

```java
package forum12218164;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        // Create an XMLStreamReader on XML input
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource xml = new StreamSource("src/forum12218164/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(xml);

        // Check the version attribute
        xsr.nextTag(); // Advance to root element
        String version = xsr.getAttributeValue("", "VERSION");
        if(!version.equals(Foo.VERSION)) {
            // Do something if the version is incompatible
            throw new RuntimeException("VERSION MISMATCH");
        }

        // Unmarshal for StAX XMLStreamReader
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);

        // Marshal the Object
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**VALID USE CASE**

***input.xml/Output***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo VERSION="123">
    <bar>ABC</bar>
</foo>
```

**INVALID USE CASE**

***input.xml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo VERSION="1234">
    <bar>ABC</bar>
</foo>
```

***Output***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: VERSION MISMATCH
    at forum12218164.Demo.main(Demo.java:23)
```

Comment: Blaise, this is essentially what we're going to do, thanks for the validation.